# Replacing portions of the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this website with the link:

http://example.com/example/index.html#page=page-1

I would like to detect the #page=page-1 portion of the URL, and add it on to http://example.com/example/indexcn.html when I click on a link (to make it http://example.com/example/indexcn.html#page=page-1).

The reason for this is because I'd like to have a bilingual website, and to switch the language between the tabs.

I've looked at onclick functions and window.location.pathname functions:

```
$("a.language").click(function(){
function reloadPageWithHash() {
var initialPage = window.location.pathname;
window.location.replace('http://example.com/#' + initialPage);
}
});
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here (noting that window.location.pathname detects 'example/index.html#page=page-1' and not just the hashtag).

Hoping someone can help me out. (:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash` for getting just the hash part.

For example:

```
$("a.language").click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://example.com/' + window.location.hash;
    return false; // prevent default action if any
});
```

*Note*: I've removed the redundant function you had inside the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
It doesn't seem to be working, though; I can't get it to tack the hashtag on to the URL.

Comment: Well, it should detect the hash part even if it is dynamically added to the URL as a result of a link click.

Comment: Add on info - 

I added the code in, but it doesn't seem to prevent the default link action: default link is index-cn.html, and the Javascript link is http://example.com, but it goes to index-cn.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.lang").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
window.location.href = 'http://example.com' + window.location.hash;
});
});
```

Played around, and that worked out for me. (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange) to listen to changes to the URL hash:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#page-1") {
        doSomething();
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$(window).hashchange(myCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, this might help:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var thisUrl = window.location.href;
    var strOptions = thisUrl.split('#');
    var strQuerystring = strOptions[1];

    var strURL = 'http://example.com/example/indexcn.html' + strQueryString;
}
```